# Is there any difference between bool() vs == in python truth testing?

Tags: python, boolean

I have two questions.

1. Can ANYTHING (objects, types, operations, functions..) in python return a boolean value when it is called upon by the bool() method?
2. Why dont the following two lines of code return the same answer?

   ```
   print (float == True)  #prints False
   print bool(float)      #prints True
   ```

Comment: because 0.02 is not equal to `True`, but implements `__nonzero__` interface, which returns `True` (because 0.02 is not zero).

Comment: `float` is `<type 'float'>`, and of course that it's different than `True`

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations.  ```==``` always consider objects of different types to be unequal - from https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#not-in

Comment: oh ok.. i understand..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two, `==` and `bool()`, are different. `==` is for equality testing, whereas `bool()` returns the result of truth value testing for the object passed to it as parameter.

According to documentation of `bool()` -

> **class bool([x])**
>
> Return a Boolean value, i.e. one of True or False. x is converted using the standard truth testing procedure. If x is false or omitted, this returns False; otherwise it returns True.

The standard truth testing procedure can be found in [the documentation -](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing)

> Any object can be tested for truth value, for use in an if or while condition or as operand of the Boolean operations below. The following values are considered false:
>
> 1. `None`
> 2. `False`
> 3. zero of any numeric type, for example, `0`, `0L`, `0.0`, `0j`.
> 4. any empty sequence, for example, `''`, `()`, `[]`.
> 5. any empty mapping, for example, `{}`.
> 6. instances of user-defined classes, if the class defines a `__nonzero__()` or `__len__()` method, when that method returns the integer zero or bool value False.
>
> All other values are considered `True` — so objects of many types are always true.

When you do `bool(float)`, you are checking the truth value for `float`, which is True.

But when you do `float == True`, you are doing equality (please note this is not truth value testing, it is equality). In this case `float` and `True` are not equal so that results in `False`.

Comment: thanks.. I have another question.. so i understand that "float" is a type. But what would I classify  "True" as?

Comment: A singleton immutable object? Or a bool: `>>> type(False)` says `<type 'bool'>`.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes. [The docs for bool() say](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#bool):

> *class* **bool**([*x*])
>
> Return a Boolean value, i.e. one of True or False. *x* is converted using the standard truth testing procedure.

The [standard truth testing procedure](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing) works on any object:

> Any object can be tested for truth value, for use in an if or while condition or as operand of the Boolean operations below. The following values are considered false: [...] All other values are considered true — so objects of many types are always true.

2. `float` is not equal to True. However, when asking "is `float` a truthy value", i.e. would `if float:` evaluate the true branch or the false branch, the answer is "yes, it would evaluate the true branch".

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes every object in Python returns a boolean value, when used with `bool` which calls the `__nonzero__`-method of this object
2. because the first `print` does not call the `__nonzero__` method.

Comment: Actually it doesn't always call `__nonzero__`. Consider: `a = object(); a.__nonzero__()` yields an `AttributeError`, yet `bool(a)` is `True`.